How to validate TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie previously set in 2FA? Using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
I've implemented a basic 2FA in ASP.NET MVC application using ASP.Net Identity class (ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager). I'm using AspNet.Identity.OWIN, please note, not a AspNetCore.Identity.
After user verifies his code that was sent by email with remember browser param, the cookie is created as expected:
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, identity);

the cookie .AspNet.TwoFactorRememberBrowser remains in browser even after logout.
Now the problem is, on a second login I need to know if this Cookie belongs to the user trying to sign in. If yes, skipping 2fa, if not applying 2fa.
I can't just check by cookie existence because the user might be using same browser of another user. I've been stuggling with it for 2 days, please any help would be appreciated.

You can use the HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync() method to authenticate a specific scheme. In your case:
var result = Context.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

Assuming the authentication succeeds you'll get an AuthenticateResult containing the ClaimsPrincipal in return. With this, you can retrieve data E.g. a user's ID from the cookie.
// Ensure the principal exists.
if (result?.Principal == null)
{
    return;
{

// Retrieve data from the principal.
var userId = result.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);

Now compare the userId against the ID of the user attempting to sign in and you'll know whether or not to ask for 2FA.
If the ID is not present in the principal, you'll have to make sure it gets added to the ClaimsIdentity before calling AuthenticationManager.SignIn(). Like so:
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

// Add claim before signing in.
identity.AddClaim(new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id))
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, identity);

Hope this helps!
